# Sum monthly sales for two products, mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have updated the code below with the two queries, they are working perfectly.

```
$query1="SELECT sum(sub_total) as limonadeTotal  from ucommerce_order_line WHERE part_number = '$part_number' group by MONTH(date_created)";

$query2="SELECT sum(sub_total) as strawberryLimonadeTotal from ucommerce_order_line WHERE part_number = '$part_number' group by MONTH(date_created)";
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Use `group by` and `sum`.

Comment: Your title is really unclear...

Comment: Please edit the question rather than posting code in the comments.

Comment: Note that price is usually DECIMAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Use Month function to group month of your date and "Sum" to create total of subtotal

```
select sum(sub_total) as total from ucommerce_order_line group by MONTH(date_created)
```

REF:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Comment: I want to use date_created. How will I setup the php array?